# Proving $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A^\top A})\ge \sum_i \lambda_i^2$ where $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $\bf A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that for an $n\times n$ real matrix $\mathbf A$ having eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$, $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A^\top A})\ge \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2$

Letting $a_{ij}$ to be a typical element of a real matrix $\bf A$, it it easily seen that $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A^\top A})=\mathrm{tr(\mathbf{AA^\top})}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^na^2_{ki}\right)$

This implies that $\sum_{k=1}^na^2_{ki}$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A^\top A}$.

This fact is also probably verified by Hadamard's inequality's '$=$' case:

$\det(\mathbf{A^\top A})=\prod_{i=1}^n(\sum_{k=1}^na^2_{ki})$

Now if $\bf A$ is symmetric then $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A^\top A})=\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf A^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2\quad$, as $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $\bf A$ whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\bf A$. So the equality case of the required inequality is easily shown. But I can't seem to prove the inequality when $\bf A$ is not symmetric.

By the C/S inequality I get, $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1^2\right)\ge\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right)^2$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Rightarrow n\times\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf A^2)\ge\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right)^2$

I could also probably say that $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A^\top A})\ge\dfrac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right)^2}{n}$ if I assume $\bf A$ to be nonsingular.

I also noticed an exercise in my textbook under 'Extrema of quadratic forms' that $\sum_{i,j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2\ge\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|^2$. I am thinking that maybe this is what needs to be shown but I have no idea about extrema of quadratic forms.

Comment: "This implies that $\sum_{k=1}^na^2_{ki}$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A^\top A}$": I have no idea what you mean by this, but it's wrong as written.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I thought that the trace was written as the sum of that quantity, that's why.

Comment: The trace is the sum of these values... therefore these values are the eigenvalues? Is that the line of reasoning here?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ki}^2$ is the *sum* of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$, but that doesn't mean that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ki}^2$ is an eigenvalue for each $i$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes that's what I thought, which is completely rubbish now that I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use $x^2+y^2- 2xy=(x-y)^2\geq 0$ so that

$$ \mbox{Tr} (A^TA - A^2) = \sum_{i<j} (a_{ij}^2+a_{ji}^2 - 2 a_{ij} a_{ji})= \sum_{i<j} (a_{ij}-a_{ji})^2\geq 0$$
showing also that equality is achieved precisely when $A$ is symmetric

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to use a Schur decomposition.  That is: there exists a unitary matrix $U$ and upper-trinagular $T$ such that $A = UTU^*$.  Note in particular that $T$ is similar to $A$, and the diagonal entries of $T$ are its eigenvalues. From there, note that
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A^\top A) = 
\operatorname{trace}(A^*A) = 
\operatorname{trace}(UT^*TU^*) = 
\operatorname{trace}(T^*T) \\
= \sum_{i,j=1}^n |t_{ij}|^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^n |t_{ii}|^2
$$